# Local limit theorem for not-identically distributed series?

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

I'm wondering if there is a local limit theorem for sums of independent random variables $X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$ which are independent but not identically distributed? I know some form of CLT holds with the Lyupanov or Lindberg conditions. If $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are integer valued and satisfy Lyupanov or Lindberg conditions (or something similar) do we still get a local limit theorem?